# Is there a way to use numpy string array functions on object arrays containing strings?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I had to store strings in a object array and i would like to use on it the functions reserved to charachter arrays

I'm using numpy arrays to store DNA sequences for data processing.
I'm preatty new to Numpy and datascience in general.
I had to use `object` arrays instead of charachter arrays as charachter arrays would chop off most of my sequence as it is usually >300 characters long.
I need to estimate the hoverall GC content of all the sequences together and the `numpy.count()` method would be the perfect tool but it only works obviusly on character arrays.
Is there a way to transform my array in the proper way to use this methods or an alternative way I can use?

```
   allCpG = np.loadtxt(CpGfile, dtype = str, delimiter = "\t", skiprows = 1)
   msk = allCpG[:,0] == chro
   CpGseqs = np.empty((allCpG[msk].shape[0],), dtype = object)
   nonCpGseqs = np.empty((allCpG[msk].shape[0],), dtype = object)
   with open(chrofile) as file:
      next(file)
      seq = ""
      for line in file:
          seq += line[:-1].upper()
   for i in range(allCpG[msk].shape[0]):
      CpGseqs[i] = seq[int(allCpG[msk][i][1]):int(allCpG[msk][i][2])]
      randindex = np.random.randint(0,len(seq)-len(CpGseqs[i]))
      nonCpGseqs[i] = seq[randindex : randindex + len(CpGseqs[i])]`
```

Every entry in CpGseqs is a string long at least 300 nucleotides and it would be chopped off if I used `dtype = str` instead

Comment: `f=np.frompyfunc(lambda astr: astr.count(), 1,1)` creates a function that can operate on your array.

Comment: The `np.char` functions apply string methods to arrays.  They aren't particularly fast, so if they don't work for you, don't worry.